# How to Hide/view the portlets in liferay Portal?

Tags: portlet, liferay, icefaces

I m developing portlets on liferay portal using icefaces, i want to hide/view the portlet programmaticaly from an action written in my managed bean. 
so please help me ASAP?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the method 
`ActionResponse.setWindowState(WindowState.MINIMIZED)` from an action of your portlets.
When talking about actions, I am referring to the ActionResponse and EventResponse classes of the portlets API.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar. If there is no data found on the portlet I usually hide it. I have check box in preference, I enable that only when needed. 
https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/implementing-configurable-portlet-preferences